# Pagination creates an error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Im trying to paginate a search to bring back pages of 18 items. Previously i had this code working code:

```
    $productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('id')->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');
```

I add on paginate to this as shown in the docs

```
    $productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('id')->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC')->paginate(18);
```

And get an error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in group statement is ambiguous
```

Any ideas on how to paginate the statement?

Comment: No, no, no... Use proper relationships and eager loading instead. You are overthinking the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccesarily the pagination which is causing the issue, the error is caused by your group by.

You should place the table name / alias name prior to the id EG:

```
 $productsQuery = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->leftJoin('reviews', 'reviews.products_id', '=', 'products.id')->select('products.*', DB::raw('AVG(ratings) as ratings_average' ))->groupBy('product.id OR reviews.id')->orderBy('ratings_average', 'DESC');
```

Please see the ammended statement above, note that copy pasting it won't work, you'll see to change that groupby argument.

You should also visit the docs on Eloquent, you have approached this in a way where you're fighting laravel. I would suggest getting a tighter grip on the ORM used.

Good luck!

Comment: The group by works without the pagination, so it is definitely the error causer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory here:

```
Column 'id' in group statement is ambiguous
```

so you need to make

```
`groupBy('id')`
```

more explicit, by telling which `id` (from which table, as each table used in your query features `id` column) you want to be used for grouping.

Comment: "Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually." taken from the docs. how would i do this?

Comment: it does not mean it is not working, but that it works less efficient that without using `groupBy()`. It may be no problem anyway but you need to test that. Custom paginator is documented in official docs